# How to share limited resources between concurrently running tasks using Rust futures?

Tags: concurrency, rust, future

I'm implementing a system that processes a certain kind of task asynchronously in Rust. In order to do this, I am using the [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate (the 0.2 beta version).

Processing one of these tasks requires temporary but exclusive use of a certain type of resource, of which there are a fixed number of in the system.

Keep in mind that this all takes place in a concurrent context: multiple threads may be trying to process a task at once. A simplified version of the interface I've been using is this:

```rust
// A fixed number of these are held by the System, and a TaskFuture needs one to complete.
pub struct Resource;

pub struct System {
    // how should the system hold Resources?
}

impl System {
    pub fn queue_task(&self, data: TaskData) -> TaskFuture {
        TaskFuture { system: self }
    }
}

pub struct TaskFuture<'a> {
    system: &'a System,
}

impl<'a> Future for TaskFuture<'a> {
    type Item = ?;
    type Error = ?;
    fn poll(&mut self, cx: &mut Context) -> Result<Async<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        /* how can I implement this? */
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I'm not quite sure what's the best way to implement such a system.

My first thought would be to have the `System` hold several `Mutex<Resource>`s, and have `TaskFuture::poll` try to get one if available, and if not return `NotReady` (though I'm not sure how I would wake the future up later in that scenario).

At any rate, I get the feeling that maybe I should avoid using the `std` synchronization primitives in a `futures`-based context unless absolutely necessary, so is there a more idiomatic `futures`-based solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like a "pool" to me, e.g. a database connection pool, thread pool, etc.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah, that's definitely what it is.